# Очередная проблема с Maven

Tags: java, android, maven

Возникла какая-то дурацкая проблема с этим Maven. Я захотел добавить в проект зависимость, добавил ее в pom.xml но ничего не вышло. Тогда я кликнул правой кнопкой мыши на проекте и выбрал там пункт Maven, затем выбрал Update project. После этого работавший проект, вдруг перестал запускаться без каких-либо причин.

В LogCat появилась ошибка такого вида:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.synch, PID: 16267
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.my.synch/synch.ui.activities.concreteactivities.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "synch.ui.activities.concreteactivities.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.synch-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.my.synch-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "synch.ui.activities.concreteactivities.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.synch-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.my.synch-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
    ... 11 more
```

С MainActivity все в порядке - она существует, я ее вообще не менял, а до этого она работала нормально.
Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: Может `mvn clean` поможет? А затем `mvn install`.

Comment: это по всей видимости какие-то консольные команды? А где их выполнять? Я слабо знаком с Maven поэтому прошу не судить строго

Comment: @Vartlok если вам есть что сказать по теме то рад буду послушать а ваши сентенции по поводу радиуса кривизны моих рук мне мало чем помогут разве что потешат ваше личное чсв но мы же тут не ради этого. . Я уже сказал, что с Maven знаком мало и не отрицаю что проблема в том, что я чтото не понимаю. Более того если вы внимательно прочтете вопрос то сможете заметить что я нигде не говорил про "дурацкий maven" а говорил про дурацкую проблему. Выполнить Update project и получить  неработающий проект это странно. В общем буду рад услышать чтото конструктивное а не "читай ман" или "у тебя кривые руки"

Comment: @Vartlok, не могли бы вы не обвинять пользователей, не зная наверняка причин проблемы? Да и зная - тоже?

Answer (score 1):

Это ошибка означает что какой-то класс не прилинкован (т.е. не добавлен в конечную сборку). Осмелюсь предположить что этот класс отсутствующий класс - это класс основного приложения (т.е. не зависимости).

Прежде всего нужно попробовать, как уже советовали выше, выполнить полную очистку проекта. Это можно сделать выполнив в директории с проектом комманду `mvn clean`. Если Вы работаете с ОС Windows то проще всего будет сделать это из IDE (в IntelliJ IDEA это можно сделать зайдя в меню *Build* → *Clean Project*). После этого попробовать собрать и запустить приложение.

Могу посоветовать так же попробовать сделать импорт проекта в IDE еще раз. В IDEA это можно сделать через меню *File* → *Import Project*.

Если и это не помогло, то тут может быть несколько вариантов.

1. Я бы для начала проинспектировал вывод `.class` файлов, которые должны попасть в конечную сборку. Желательно проинспектировать саму сборку, например с помощью [этого](http://www.decompileandroid.com/) инструмента или dex2jar+JD-gui как в этом [гайде](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/apk-whatitis.php). Если сборка не полная, то нужно курить отладочный вывод Maven. Если сборка выглядит полной то можно попробовать вариант №2.
2. Класс не проходит проверку. Что-бы исключить этот вариант необходимо при установке приложения проинспектировать вывод программы dexopt в LogCat (не забудьте снять фильтр на package вашего приложения).  Там скорее будет все видно.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, к сожалению не могу сейчас проверить. Однако я использую Windows, насколько понимаю mvn clean это команда для выполнения в консоли linux. Кроме того, я использую Eclipse, поэтому настройки IDEA для меня к сожалению не подходят. В Eclipse также есть пункт меню Clean project в меню Build/ Возможно это то, о чем вы говорили, однако я не раз пробовал, это к сожалению не работало.

Comment: "mvn clean" можно выполнить и в Windows, просто несколько сложнее. Можно посмотреть здесь http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/.

Comment: По поводу Eclipse: clean build должен делать тоже самое по идее.